# Git command for count of commit messages containing a string, per user

Tags: git

I know about git shortlog -sne, and git grep, but I need to kinda combine the two.

I'm searching for the number of occurrences of a string in the commit message, per user. I'd like the output to be:

```
Will: 54
Dave: 34
... etc.
```

Can someone help?

Comment: String in the commit message or in touched code?

Comment: In the commit message. Sorry, I should have said that.

Comment: What's your plattform? On POSIX you could do this with a simple shell script.

Comment: All I know is we use Solaris. We develop on Windows though... which is where git is running. I only need to do this locally.

Comment: `git grep` does not search the commit messages, so your mentioning it in the question is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If by `git sne` you mean `git shortlog -sne` then it can take a `--grep` option to grep the commit messages.

```
git shortlog -sne --grep="a string"
```

Comment: I just found out... add the `--all` parameter to shortlog

Comment: git shortlog -sne --grep="merge conflict" --> 29 merge conflicts :(